# Creating Debian package: How to create folder using rule file in user/Desktop?

Tags: deb, packaging

I am packing .deb and I want to create folder on the Desktop
I am creating folders using :

```
mkdir -p $(CURDIR)/debian/tmp/usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps/
mkdir -p $(CURDIR)/debian/uome/username/Desktop/myfolder
```

The ptoblem is usernmae above how can i enter the anyones's Ubuntu's username ;

Please Help

Comment: Packages **should not** create anything in any user's home directories.

Comment: but how could I create .desktop file on the desktop?

Comment: You don't. Whatever application this is for can create a launcher when the user runs it, but packages don't add anything to user home directories.

Comment: Create a script which does the work, and have it run for users via a `.desktop` file in `/etc/xdg/autostart` instead.